# Unable to run Express.js server

Tags: node.js, express

I when running the below code, i am getting error. I have attached the error trace and also the express.js server code below:

```
app.configure(function() {
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\dashboard\server\index.js:17:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

The code:

```
'use strict';

var express = require("express"),
  contacts = require("./db_interactions"),
  version = require('./package.json').version,
  program = require('commander'),
  app = express();

/* cli */
program
  .version(version)
  .option('-p, --port <n>', 'port number', parseInt)
  .parse(process.argv);

var port = program.port || 4000;

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  /* Website you wish to allow to connect */
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || '*');
  /* Request methods you wish to allow */
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  /* Request headers you wish to allow */
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  /* Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent */
  /* to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions) */
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  /* Pass to next layer of middleware */
  if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.get("/:appName/users", contacts.index);
app.delete('/:appName/deletereleases/:id', contacts.deleteReleases);

app.listen(port, "127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of express you are using? In express4.x, app.configure() method is removed.
Consult [this](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x) github wiki for migrating from express3.x to express4.x.

Comment: Hi sam,
I am on express 3.x only
my dependencies are
"dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "~3.8.8",
    "express": "~3.0.6",
    "underscore": "~1.6.0",
    "async": "~0.8.0",
    "node-uuid": "~1.4.1",
    "reload": "~0.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "~0.9.1",
    "moment": "~2.6.0",
    "commander": "^2.2.0"
  }
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using app.use outside app.configure.

Comment: @raman can you run `npm ls express` to make sure that Express 3.x is installed?